# Storing and extracting pickle file from CSV or DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn, pickle

I am storing sklearn models with pickle.
But the environment I am working in only allows the persistence of CSV and DataFrame Data.

I tried saving models to DataFrames with:

```
#create empty DataFrame
model_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["modelstring"])

#Save one model to each row
for model in range(1, len(model_dict)):
    model_df.loc[model] = pickle.dumps(model_dict[model], protocol = 3)

...

#Store and reload csv file
model_df["modelstring"].to_csv("models.csv")
model_df2 = pd.read_csv("models.csv")

...
#Load Model from Pickle 
model = pickle.loads(model_df2.loc[1].modelstring)
```

But when reading them out, the files are not byte codes anymore, but strings, which I can't convert back to byte.

input format: b'\x80\x03csklearn.svm.classes\nOneClassSVM\nq\x...'

output format: 'b\'\x80\x03csklearn.svm.classes\nOneClassSVM\nq...'

Is there any way to store the models in the csv and being able to read them back out?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you instead want to save them as pickled files? `model_df["modelstring"].to_pickle("models.pkl")`

Comment: As mentioned, I cannot use any dataformat except CSV/DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several issues replicating your code (there are some bugs). But I managed to solve it :)

You can use `hex` when storing, and use `bytes.fromhex()` when reading from files.

It goes like this:

```
#create empty DataFrame
model_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["modelstring"])

#Save one model to each row
for model in range(1, len(model_dict)):
    model_df.loc[model] = pickle.dumps(model_dict[model], protocol = 3).hex()

...

#Store and reload csv file
model_df["modelstring"].to_csv("models.csv")
model_df2 = pd.read_csv("models.csv")

...
#Load Model from Pickle 
model = pickle.loads(bytes.fromhex(model_df2.loc[1].modelstring))
```